# Not able to change bar color through .css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, graph

Here is all the javascript code I am using:

```
var marginEducation = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 300},
widthEducation = 1000,
heightEducation = 460;

const svgEducation = d3.select("#Education")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("widthEducation", widthEducation + marginEducation.left + marginEducation.right)
    .attr("heightEducation", heightEducation + marginEducation.top + marginEducation.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${marginEducation.left}, ${marginEducation.top})`);

d3.csv("csvData/DeveloperProfile/Education/Education.csv").then( function(data) {

console.log(data)

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.EducationCount = +d.EducationCount;
});

const xEducation = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.EducationCount; }) * 1.25])
    .range([ 0, widthEducation]);
svgEducation.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${heightEducation})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xEducation).tickSize(0))
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xEducation).tickValues([]))
    .select(".domain").remove()

const yEducation = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ 0, heightEducation ])
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.EducationAnswer; }))
    .padding(0.2)

svgEducation.append("g")
    
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yEducation).tickSize(0))
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yEducation).tickPadding(30))
    .select(".domain").remove()

svgEducation.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", xEducation(0) )
    .attr("y", d => yEducation(d.EducationAnswer))
    .attr("width", d => xEducation(d.EducationCount))
    .attr("height", yEducation.bandwidth())

svgEducation.selectAll(".text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
    return d.EducationCount;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return yEducation(d.EducationAnswer) + (yEducation.bandwidth()/2) + 4;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xEducation(d.EducationCount) + d.EducationCount.toString().length * 5;
    });
})
```

And this is the section of the .css file that is applicable:

```
.bar {
  color: steelblue;
}
```

However, when this runs, it creates a black bar instead of the steelblue as it is stated in the .css file. I've tried putting the css code directly within the base html file under the  header, but this does not work either, so I am thinking this is an issue with the javascript code, but I am not sure where as I have tested quite a number of potential options. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Are you trying to use svg to change the color or css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: I had to add the line

```
.attr("class", "bar")
```

to the function in order to create the class that could then be edited within the main .css file

Comment: Right. When you do `svgEducation.selectAll(".bar")`, you are selecting everything within `svgEducation` that is classed `bar`. At that point in time, there are no such items so the selection is empty. You then call `.enter().append("rect")`, which appends a new `rect` for every item in the bound data. There's no reason for those to be classed `bar`, though, unless you specify that attribute using `.attr("class", "bar")`, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's a misunderstanding in the CSS class usage for SVG elements. Unlike regular HTML elements, SVG elements don't use the "color" property to change the fill color of the bars.

```
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
```

With this change, the bars should now appear with the "steelblue" fill color as you intended. The "fill" property in CSS is specifically used to set the fill color of SVG shapes like rectangles, circles, and paths.

(if it didn't work try applying **!important** after **steelblue**)

Comment: I have tried both methods, and the bar is still appearing as black. I hadn't tried the !important method yet so I was hoping that would work (had already tried the change from color -> fill and that hadn't changed anything) but unfortunately the bars are still appearing as black